# How to get an index number in Hexo article loop "for each"?

Tags: javascript, templates, themes, hexo

In Hexo.js, when you want to output some articles, you loop using `.sort`, `.limit` and `.each`, for example:

```
<% site.posts.sort('date', 'desc').limit(8).each(function(post){ %>
    <div id="post-1" class="post">
        <%= post.title %>
        all the other post tags and content
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

How do you set the id number `post-X` to be dynamically incremented, for example first post would get `id="post-1"`, second `id="post-2"` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% site.posts.sort('date', 'desc').limit(8).each(function(post, i){ %>
    <div id="post-<%=i+1%>" class="post">
        <%= post.title %>
        all the other post tags and content
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

As you can see, there is an additional parameter, `i`, which means index.